# Why is the text file's information not being read into my array and then listbox?

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to C# and am experiencing a problem. My program keeps throwing an error per my try catch. I have looked over everything and changed things, but nothing seems to work. Could it be the reading of the text file? or the array? or the transfer into the listbox? I really need some help with this. It has become nothing but a headache.
    ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;

namespace Total_Sales_BBrantley
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Declare variable to hold the amount of sales

            // Declare variable to act as the accumulator
            const int SIZE = 100;
            double[] allSales = new double[SIZE];
            double total = 0.0;
            double average;
            double highest = allSales[0];
            double lowest = allSales[2000];

            int count = 0;

            // Declare a StreamReader variable.
            StreamReader readFile;

            // Open the file and get a StreamReader object using a relative path
            readFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

            while (!readFile.EndOfStream && count < allSales.Length)
            {
                allSales[count] = int.Parse(readFile.ReadLine());

                // Increment count
                count++;
            }

            // Close the file
            readFile.Close();

            lstSales.Items.Add("The file contains " + count + " items:");
            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
                lstSales.Items.Add(allSales[index]);

            }



            // Display the total
            double sum = allSales.Sum();
            lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();

            total += sum;
            average = total / allSales.Length;
            lblAverage.Text = average.ToString();

            for (int index = 1; index < allSales.Length; index++)
            {
                if (allSales[index] > highest)
                {
                    highest = allSales[index];
                }
                lblHighest.Text = highest.ToString();

            }
            for (int index = 1; index < allSales.Length; index++)
            {
                if (allSales[index] < lowest)
                {
                    lowest = allSales[index];
                }
                lblLowest.Text = lowest.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Display an error message on bad input from file 
            MessageBox.Show("Error calculating the sales.");
        }

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Closes the application
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post a sample of the input file. Also, for arrays you can use `lstSales.Items.AddRange(allSales);`

Comment: Can you post the exception as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read all your code, but there's an error just at the start:

```
const int SIZE = 100;
double[] allSales = new double[SIZE];
<snip>
double lowest = allSales[2000];
```

You've declared the array to have 100 elements, but you're trying to access the 2,000th.  Your array isn't that big, so you'll get an IndexOutOfRangeException on that line.

Arrays have fixed sizes in C# once declared.  If you need the size to change, use the generic List class.

Comment: Also, once you're more up to speed, look into using LINQ.  It could calculate most of these values (max, min etc.) in one line, rather than you doing it yourself and using looping.

Answer (score 0):

Bulding on martin_costello's answer, perhaps you could initialize lowest and highest like this:

```
double highest = double.MinValue;
double lowest = double.MaxValue;
```

Or at the very least, initialize these values after you have loaded your data!

Also, a tip for debugging: if you're getting an error, either display the error returned by the catch or comment out the try/catch so that you can see the error.

An example of the former:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Display an error message on bad input from file 
   MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Error calculating the sales: ", ex.Message, "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
}
```

Comment: Here is the input file:                                         1245.67,
1189.55,
1098.72,
1456.88,
2109.34,
1987.55,
1872.36